# Selling photographs: Getty or Shutterstock?

Tags: selling, stock-photography, micro-stock

I've had around [11 photos on Getty](http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/search/photographer?excludenudity=true&family=creative&license=rf&page=1&phrase=richard%20stelmach&photographer=richard%20stelmach&sort=best&alloweduse=availableforalluses#license) now for around a year:

However, none have sold.

Getty also makes you sign an exclusive agreement so you can't have the same images on other stock sites.

I have more images to upload but I'm wondering if it's best to try another site out such as Shutterstock. Where the commission is very small but volume should be higher.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that your photos would necessarily sell better on other stock platforms. Most already feature many photos that are very similar to yours, as well as many that are of higher technical (less noise, no sensor dust) as well as photographic quality (composition, subject matter). So the chance of anyone even running across your specific photos are already pretty low, and then they would have to choose your photographs over all the other available ones.

You should try to evaluate other photographs in similar categories (landscape, wildlife) across different platforms to figure out what makes them relevant to whom and try to improve your photography and image selection accordingly if you want to sell stock photos on a more regular basis. Stock photography is usually not about photos that individual people (meaning: you) find interesting or "good", but about certain parameters (again, technical and photographic) that make them relevant for a larger number of people.